# Android timed http request starving

Tags: android, multithreading, webview

Hello i'm developing an adroid app that uses the std web view and chrome browser. 
I need to perform 1 http request every 500 millisec to the server but i see that the thread is somehow stopped or delayed, the php called to the server performs a log into my database with the request time and at certain time i receive no requests, a little time after i receive a stack of reqeusts all at once.

Is there any lock or sleep performed over threads ?

I made a couple of tests and the action was performed by javascript in the beginning and had same problem so i moved the control over an android thread to avoid problems over the js but even the thread iside the android app have the same issue.

We discovered that if we move the tablet and force a page rotation the app goes alive again and start working again.

Any idea ?

I'm not developing the android app directly i take care of the web part of the app (server side application and html+js. So my android experience is a bit limited, i searched over web and found nothing to help my friend solve this out.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is the timing logic in the code is a bit broken. 500 milliseconds is not much more than typical round trip latency you might see on many 3G and 4G networks. If the code doesn't correctly account for the possibility that the request will take longer than the repeat time, you may get bugs where the code winds up waiting longer and longer.

Here's an analogy: Say you are supposed to go to the store every hour. It's 1:00 and you're about to go to the store. You realize that you need to go to the store next at 2:00. So you go to the store and come back. Now you need to wait until it's 2:00. But if it's already 2:05, you'll be waiting *way* too long.

Comment: I forgot to say that this app works only over a wifi connection but maybe raising timeouts to 1 sec shuold fix the problem ?

Well request time maybe is too high. THe strange thing is that wwe had the same problem when we sent request by ajax with a similar structure. I used an setInterval ( funct , 500 ) And the funct checked a global var used a semaphore to be sure not more 1 request at time.

Comment: That sounds like it should be okay. Unfortunately, issues with setInterval and setTimeout have been widely reported and it's not quite clear what's going on.

Comment: That's why we sent control to andorid, (i have to say that using the std browser everything works perfectly with those timed ajax queries) .

At this time the only thing my js do is to call the andorid function every xxx ms that read a var populated after the last http request and after that the var is emptyed..

Comment: My friend is now testing the network, cause on a different network configuration the system is working fine even with 500ms spllet time over threads .... hope he will fix the porblem ... tomorrow evenining is the big day ..... :(

So maybe the wifi have some problems ...